# Cannot log in to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login

All of a sudden I cannot log into Magento, at all.

I used the .htaccess to force SSL. This broke things so I have turned it off again.

It started with another User being unable to log in. Meanwhile I still could. No I cannot log in nor any other users.

I get no errors and submitting the log in form just redirects to `/index.php/admin/index/index/key/bbdbb9580dbc6aec7b25c9cd96277058/` with no errors at all.

Nothing has changed other than turning on SSL and then turning it off via the .htaccess file. Apache has been restarted too.

**EDIT**

If I use the password reset form and reset my password and then log in it works. Log out and it fails again.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? In last resort you could delete all sessions in `/var/session/`.

Comment: I just tried that, no change. Is there any other cache folder I can delete?

Comment: All cache folders are under `/var/cache`. Could you specify the Magento version you are using? Are you using something like Memcached for sessions?

Comment: Not memcache. How can I find the version, its usually at the bottom when I log in. But I cannot log in.

Comment: You can find the version inside app/Mage.php

Comment: 1.9.01 - maybe?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration, remember you may be using REDIS or Memcached for your cache, so clearing that folder might or might not help.

This looks like it has successfully logged you in, but it's still showing you the login page.

This usually relates to the cookie domain.

Firstly, clear your BROWSER cache & sessions, or try incognito.

Secondly, take a look in your database for rows with the path "web/cookie/cookie_path" and "web/cookie/cookie_domain" in your core_config_data table.  It might be that you updated this value, and you need to revert it.

You may also find that if you have multiple Magento admin logins running on subdomains, that this issue is caused by setting the cookie domain to act for all subdomains.  This means you can login, but you'll always be shown the login page.  Always a pain on development enviornments!

Comment: There is now way I am using REDIS or Memcached.

I have been using different browsers and incognito to try and log in. All result in the same issue, no errors and no log in. `web/cookie/cookie_pat` value is NULL and `web/cookie/cookie_domain` value is NULL. The site has no sub domains and is not on a subdomain.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: It seemed to just work one day